# How can stop nuxtjs wheel/scroll event of input type number field?

Tags: nuxtjs

Here, need to stop increase/decrease value of field when scrolled.

```
<input
   type="number"
   class="form-control"
   id="phone"
   v-model="phone"
   placeholder="Mobile No"
   name="phone"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @wheel event with "$event.target.blur()" value as following...

```
<input
   type="number"
   class="form-control"
   id="phone"
   v-model="phone"
   placeholder="Mobile No"
   name="phone"
   @wheel="$event.target.blur()"
/>
```